# Can we add [Java-Development-Kit] as a synonym of [JDK]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Can we make [java-development-kit](/questions/tagged/java-development-kit) a tag synonym of [jdk](/questions/tagged/jdk)?

Comment: Why would that be a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um... There are no questions tagged [java-development-kit](/questions/tagged/java-development-kit).

I think you are misunderstanding tag synonyms. They are meant for two **existing, well established** tags.

This way synonyms can be used if there are too many questions with one tag to retag to another. The tags are then made synonyms.